# Why is my angular binding read only in a bootstrap UI modal in an MVC5 project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to pop up a modal to get some input, but the angular binding via `ng-model` seems to be read only. This is my modal markup:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="signatureWindow.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Signature Capture</h4>
    </div>
    <input type="text" width="100px" ng-model="theName" />
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button ng-click="accept()" class="btn btn-primary">Accept</button>
        <button ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Then, I invoke this modal as follows:

```
$scope.getSignatureModal = function(signatureBase64) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'signatureWindow.html',
        controller: 'SignatureModalController',
        size: 'lg',
        resolve: {
            signatureData: function() {
                return signatureBase64;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function(signatureData) {
        alert('Signed');
        signatureBase64 = signatureData;
    }, function() {
        alert('Canceled');
    });
};
```

And the following controller code for the modal:

```
MlamAngularApp.controller('SignatureModalController', function($scope, $modalInstance, signatureData) {
    $scope.base64 = signatureData;
    $scope.thename = "NamesRus";

    $scope.accept = function() {
        debugger;
        $modalInstance.close($scope.thename);
    }

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }

});
```

The modal pops up as expected, and the input has the initial value "NamesRus", but when I close the modal, invoking `accept` in the modal controller, `$scope.thename` still has it's initial value, not any new value I type when the modal is active. What could be wrong here?

NOTE: At the `debugger` breakpoint in `accept`, no matter what I type in the modal's input, `theName` still has the initial assigned value.

MORE: My Plunker for this works fine. It's when in-place, in an ASP.NET MVC5 project, that I get the strange behaviour.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit - is the `signatureData` in `modalInstance.result.then` not the value you wrote in the input? I ran a basically identical modal test and `console.log`ging the equivalent of your `signatureData` shows the value I wrote in the input field so it's working fine. Also, you're missing the closing brace of your input element, but that shouldn't have an effect on the outcome though.

Comment: @Fissio No, the `signatureData` in `result.then` is still the initial value, i.e. `NamesRus`. Thanks for the closing bracket.  but right, it doesn't affect this, just a hasty copy and paste thing.

Comment: Looks ok. Could you reproduce the behaviour in a plunker ? In my mind this should work.

Comment: when open the modal bootstrap modal creates a new scope . when you close that modal its destroyes the scope. so if you reopen the modal its a new scope so its recompile the controller with initial value.

Comment: @Fisherman I only open and close the modal once.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you mix up two differents scopes.

If you want several variables to be passed to and retrieved from the modal you have to mention them:

1. in the resolve attribute

   ```
   resolve: {modalData: function (){return {signatureData:$scope.base64,name:$scope.theName}}}
   ```
2. pass modalData as dependencie to your controller

   ```
   MlamAngularApp.controller('SignatureModalController', function($scope,     $modalInstance, modalData)
   ```
3. update the modal controller $scope with modalData

   ```
   $scope.signatureData = modalData.signatureData;
   $scope.name=modalData.name;
   ```
4. invoke

   ```
   $modalInstance.close({signatureData:$scope.base64,name:$scope.theName})
   ```
5. reassign the original $scope with the result of promise

   ```
   modalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
       $scope.base64 = data.signatureData;
       $scope.thename=data.name;
   }
   ```

take a look at this plunker forked from ui-boostrap modal orginal example: http://plnkr.co/edit/whLSYt?p=info

Comment: Thanks, but it seems my shortening of the example code gave the wrong message. I am not even trying to return `thename` from the modal scope, it is strictly local, and only used to indicate that the modal UI isn't updating its very own scope, the one introduced by `SignatureModalController`. It looks like this problem might be local to my project.

Comment: This was due to an out of date bootstrap ui script. Thanks anyway.